# Mercurial - High CPU Usage when Pushing Changes to Server Repository

Tags: windows, version-control, mercurial, versioning, tortoisehg

We recently implemented Mercurial within one of our teams at our company as a trial before rolling it out to everyone. So far, everything has gone pretty good. But when we let another team access to Mercurial, we ran into an issue when pushing changes from our local repository to the server repository.

The python.exe process is using close to 100% CPU on the server when a push is in progress. And this is with one single push going on. It was at originally at 100% but we added server.uncompressed = true in the hgrc and it seemed a help a little bit but it's still high.

The server is a VM running Windows Server 2008 Standard on an Intel Xeon 3 GHz with 2 GB RAM.

Doing a Google search yielded no useful information. Does SO have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you storing large files in mercurial?

Comment: None that are excessively large. There are a lot of files (it's a website project) but the biggest file is only about 18 MB.

Comment: This is basically a bug report, and as duchies think it is much better to report it at mercurial@selenic.com where the Mercurial community and developers can help you debug this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you really sure there's a problem somewhere ?

I really don't see what's wrong with using all the CPU power at disposition to do the job.

Using compression probably "helped" because python has to access to wait for the decompression library to do its work.

Do you prefer to wait for 5 seconds at 20% load, or 1 second at 100% load ?

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't care about the CPU cycles either. But this is with one single push. What happens when you have more people using Mercurial and pushing at the same time? We have about 7 teams that will be using Mercurial once it's fully implemented and we don't know if they will be able to use it if this issue remains.

Comment: pushing locks the repository, so the other user will have to wait until the completion of the operation.

Comment: This is not for a single repository though. Each team has their own repositories that they will be working with.

Comment: Then the CPU is at 100% still, but each job runs a little slower. Still not really seeing the issue unless a push is taking more than a 20 seconds right now, and you think it may reach minutes with multiple users. Is your repo really large? Was the contents of your changesets quite large as well? If not, then I'm not sure where the problem may have come from.

Comment: A 35 MB push with one to two changesets is taking about 5 minutes right now.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into [issue #135](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/139). Try hosting the repository over https instead of accessing it via ssh.